# hls live streaming using ffmpeg in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am new to ffmpeg and I am trying to create live streaming app (HLS) and I want Live broadcasting rather than VOD.

I am able to use ffmpeg through terminal and create .ts files from m4v but I am not getting how to achieve the same thing in iPhone.

My approach is to create .ts files at iPhone end and then send it to server.

I am not sure if this approach is correct, If this correct how I can create .ts files then otherwise what's the right approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create .ts file from iPhone, you will need the [FFmpegWrapper](https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper) library and then do like this,

```
NSString *outputPath = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out.m3u8"];

    FFmpegWrapper *wrapper = [[FFmpegWrapper alloc] init];
    [wrapper convertInputPath:inputPath outputPath:outputPath segmentDuration:SEGMENT_DURATION options:nil progressBlock:
     ^(NSUInteger bytesRead, uint64_t totalBytesRead, uint64_t totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

         //Do loading here


     } completionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

         // Do whatever after it is complete

     }];
```

Comment: Hey abhi, thanks buddy, your solution just worked. do you have any suggestions on live streaming(broadcasting mode) ? Is the right way I am implementing ? I am thinking to send .ts files to server and server send it further to other devices or may be a live url to access, what're you are comments on this ? I would like to go with best approach with regards to video quality and less delays.

Comment: I would suggest to do segmenting on the server side as it is less headache than on client side. Also you will need to make multiple playlist files at different bit rates. That way, the client will switch to the most appropriate variant based on the measured network bit rate.

Comment: @Abhi : I didn't find the above function with SEGMENT_DURATION in FFMpegWrapper class. Instead of that I found this one: 

- (void) convertInputPath:(NSString*)inputPath outputPath:(NSString*)outputPath options:(NSDictionary*)options progressBlock:(FFmpegWrapperProgressBlock)progressBlock completionBlock:(FFmpegWrapperCompletionBlock)completionBlock;

I have integrated this wrapper class using pods. Is there any method to specify the segment duration using that one?

Comment: Oh ya. my mistake, here is my forked version of the library...
https://github.com/Abhijit-Kayande/FFmpegWrapper

Comment: Could the inputPath be a rtsp link?